# Scrapy get xPath attribute with getall()

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to get a build a list of IDs (which will later be used in URLs to scrape more data):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for a in response.xpath('//a[@class="imageLink"]').getall():  
        print(a)
        item = NgaItem1()
        item["itemId"] = a.attrib["assetid"]
        yield item
```

I believe I'm properly selecting the DOM elements, as `print(a)` is returning the following for each element I'm interested in:

```
<a class="imageLink" id="assetLink_A_148957" assetid="148957" assettype="A" rel=""><img style="max-width:128px;max-height:128px;" class="mainThumbImage imageDraggable" alt="" title="George Catlin - The White Cloud, Head Chief of the Iowas - 1844/1845 - Painting" rel="" offset="" onmousedown="
                                                        noclear = 1; noclear=0;
                                                " id="grid-item_A_148957" assetid="148957" src="https://images.nga.gov//assets/thumbnails/497/7/5a7e73ae456e734fe2eaf4a0a71f0e3d.jpg"></a>
```

All I need from it is the assetid 148957. The error I'm getting is `'str' object has no attribute 'attrib'`.

Comment: did you try to directly select the attribute using "@assetid" in your Xpath? I know that this works for @title for example. Xpath would be: response.xpath('//a[@class="imageLink"]/@assetid').getall()

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal answer, but I ended up using string manipulation. Some IDs were 5 digits and some where 6, so I did a bit of cleanup afterwards in Excel.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for a in response.xpath('//a[@class="imageLink"]').getall():  
        start = a.find('assetid')
        item = NgaItem1()
        item["itemId"] = a[start+9:start+15]
        print(item["itemId"])
        yield item
```